# Can i Get the Total Views of Facebook Public Video Using its Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, facebook-php-sdk

There are so many things to do using their graph API. Almost everything about a posted public video in facebook can be accessed. So is there any way to count or *get the total number of views of facebook public video*. I read about ***insights*** but i think this can only be accessed by the owner of the video. Since i don't have rights to access that, can i still get the total views of a facebook public video using graph api?

Comment: Yes indeed. I've been testing with the Graph API Explorer and no variation of post insights (or video_insights) seems to work. No errors, just empty data.

It seems crazy that you can pull massive amounts of data in terms of people's FB profiles who liked the video, and yet a simple metric like views is inaccessible... Can anyone shed light?